# C# - Merge two DataTables where rows are duplicate

Tags: c#, merge, datatable, duplicates, row

I can find lots of information about merging two DataTables and dropping duplicate rows, but I need the opposite.

I need to know if anyone has an easy way to merge two DataTables where the result of the merge is a DataTable with only rows that exist in both tables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this:

```
var intersection = table1.AsEnumerable()
                         .Intersect(table2.AsEnumerable(), DataRowComparer.Default);
```

`DataRowComparer` compares rows by their column values.

Comment: but OP wants "the result of the merge is a DataTable"?

Comment: @naveen: Then call `CopyToDataTable()`.

Comment: @bemused: yes. msdn also use `.Default` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386998.aspx. i dont think there is a `DataComparer.Instance`