# Combine 2 Datatables with the common rows only

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net

I have 2 datatables:

_wizardStepSelectUnitDataSet.WizardStepSelectUnits_UnitsSelectedInOtherAgreements

and

_wizardStepSelectUnitDataSet.WizardStepSelectUnits_SelectedUnits

The schemas are the same, I need to know which rows exist on both datatables,

How can I do that into a new datatable?

There is no CODE:
I only have 2 datatables already designed.  They are already filled with some data in memory.

I need to know which are the common rows between both datatables using one ID field.

I cant copy the code of the designer, you will be overwhelmed.

I tried this:
  var result =
                from r in
                    _wizardStepSelectUnitDataSet.WizardStepSelectUnits_UnitsSelectedInOtherAgreements.AsEnumerable()
                join c in _wizardStepSelectUnitDataSet.WizardStepSelectUnits_SelectedUnits.AsEnumerable()
                    on r.Field("UnitId") equals c.Field("UnitId")
                select r;

```
        DataRow[] dr = result.Select(
            String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.DateTimeFormat,"StartDate <= #{0}#", stopDate));
```

However I got a compiler error:
Error   7   The type arguments for method 'System.Linq.Enumerable.Select(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable, System.Func)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.  C:\BITProjects\TeamSystem\luival\refm\DEV\AgreementModule\GUI\WorkItems\UC021_HuurovereenkomstWizard_WorkItem.cs    511 28  Ceusters.REFM.AgreementModule.GUI

Thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# - Merge two DataTables where rows are duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6833454/c-merge-two-datatables-where-rows-are-duplicate)

Comment: I foound that as well, it doesn work: Error 8 'System.Data.EnumerableRowCollection<Ceusters.REFM.AgreementModule.Common.DataSets.UC021_RentalAgreements.UC021_WizardStepSelectUnitDataSet.WizardStepSelectUnits_UnitsSelectedInOtherAgreementsRow>' does n

Comment: Please add the code used and complete, formatted error to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not that good with LINQ, but maybe you want to try this approach?

```
var result = from r in dt.AsEnumerable()
                     join c in dt2.AsEnumerable()
                     on r.Field<string>("col1") equals c.Field<string>("col1")
                     select r;
```

And then for all your columns in both tables.

I'm sure there is a ways comparing complete rows instead of fields/columns.

Comment: the code compiles, but how can I access the columns of the resulting rows or how can I put that result into a datatable?

Comment: "result" is a set of DataRows so you can "foreach (DataRow row in result)". Or you can use "var" as well instead of "DataRow".

Comment: Oh. Found something new to me, too. You can use "result.CopyToDataTable()".

Answer (score 0):

Identify a unique_id field in the tables and then,

SELECT * 
  FROM table1, table2
 WHERE table1.unique_id = table2.unique_id

Once you're happy with what's returned you can build your insert statement based on the select.

Comment: No, this is wrong. its .NET code, not Sql Server Code. I have already both datatables on memory, I need to do it with .net code

Answer (score -1):

Use System.Data.DataTable.Merge() , see this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk68ew7b.aspx

EDIT: Might not be a relevant answer, I misread "exist on both tables". Yes, what you are looking for is the intersection as others have speculated.

Comment: .Merge doesnt do that, I only need the common rows of both datatables, Merge Joins ALL Rows