# How to detect that a datatable is a part of another datatable

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, linq, datatable

if i have two datatables :

```
DT1 & DT2
```

How to check if the first one contains the second one , i mean that the same rows of `DT2` is in the `DT1`.

Comment: Must all row's fields match with the same(what primary key?) row's fields of the other DataTable?

Comment: this post has nothing to do with asp.net or linq.

Comment: care to explain how comparing the data in 2 data tables has anything to do with linq or asp.net? put another way. do you think the approach would change whether you use linq or not, or whether the UI is a webpage or rich client?

Comment: it is already discussed in following link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6833454/c-sharp-merge-two-datatables-where-rows-are-duplicate

Comment: @JasonMeckley :thanks a lot , but when i insist to put the `linq` and `asp.net` tags i have a reason . could u take a look at the answer please .

Comment: just because you have a reason, doesn't make it correct. it's misleading to add these tags when your problem isn't directly related to either of these concepts/frameworks/environments.

Comment: I'm sorry ,if i made any confusion ,but at the end , the `Linq` is an important part of the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My question: *"Must all row's fields match with the same row's fields of the other DataTable?"*

Your answer: *"no just the id"*

You can first check if both `DataTables` are null or both have the same row-count. Then you can use LINQ to determine if both have the same IDs using [`Enumerable.Except`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779.aspx):

```
var dt1IDs = DT1.AsEnumerable().Select(r => r.Field<int>("id"));
var dt2IDs = DT2.AsEnumerable().Select(r => r.Field<int>("id"));
var diff = dt1IDs.Except(dt2IDs);
var equal = DT1.Rows.Count == DT2.Rows.Count && !diff.Any();
```

Explanation: `diff.Any()` returns true when there's at least one id in DT1 that is not in DT2.

**Edit**:  If the ID is **not** unique and might repeat you need to check whether all ID's in DT1 are also in DT2 and all IDs of DT2 are in DT1:

```
var DT1InDT2 = dt1IDs.Except(dt2IDs);
var DT2InDT1 = dt2IDs.Except(dt1IDs);
var equal = DT1.Rows.Count == DT2.Rows.Count && !DT1InDT2.Any() && !DT2InDT1.Any();
```

This query is efficient anyway.

---

**Edit2**: I've just seen that i've misunderstood your requiremnet a little bit. You only want to know if the first table contains the second, not vice-versa.

```
var DT2IdNotInDT1 = dt2IDs.Except(dt1IDs);
var equal = !DT2IdNotInDT1.Any();
```

Comment: I try it the first ids(200,300,146) the second ids (200,300)
so it should return true not false but it return `false`

Comment: no the ids are unique but should i rely on the diff only ?? please check the above comment

Comment: @just_name: Of course it returns false since the first table has 3 records whereas the second has only two.

Comment: then i should rely on diff only because my question is check that the first datatable contain the whole second one

Comment: @just_name: I've just seen that i've misunderstood your requiremnet a little bit. You only want to know if the first table contains the second, not vice-versa. Wait a moment, i'll edit my answer.

Comment: you do realize that linq is looping through all of the records in the both tables using a foreach loop. the syntax is compact and expressive, but don't be fooled that it's faster/effecient/etc. it's expressive and, like most tools, can actually be dangerous when used incorrectly.

Comment: @JasonMeckley: It's just looping through the `IEnumerable<int>` (the ID's) of both DataTables and uses a `HashSet<int>` internally for the second sequence passed in - that allows it to look up elements in O(1) while iterating over the first sequence to filter out elements that are contained in the second sequence. So it's not only short and elegant but also very efficient.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I wasn't implying this is not efficient. only that the OP asked a question, but expected a specific answer: "linq".

Answer (score 3):

loop through the tables and comapare fields (hopefully just the IDs). there are a number of ways to do this depending on how your datatables are structured.

Comment: hmmmm , but this is  so much !

Comment: If it takes you longer than it took you to write the question, you're doing it wrong!!

Answer (score 0):

you can use Intersect operator

var intersect = DT2.AsEnumerable().Intersect(DT1.AsEnumerable(),
                                                    DataRowComparer.Default);

Comment: You'll need more than that one line won't you?